# Maven - Load resources from JAR?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a feeling I'm missing something critical when it comes to bundling resources in JAR files using Maven. My directory structure is the standard Maven one 
(i.e. \src\main\java, \src\main\resources).

When using the IDE I reference the resource files as \main\resources\images\blah... and it works fine, but when Maven bundles the JAR file it puts the paths relative to the root ("\images\blah"), so none of the paths are correct.

My question is two-fold really, the first being am I missing something obvious? The second being what's the best way to handle this issue? I know I could just replace all the paths when I go to bundle everything for deployment, or surround all the paths in try/catch blocks, or even change the maven output directory, but I feel like these are in-elegant and I'm missing something.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I reference the resource files like this:
`getClass().getResource("/main/resources/images/lightboardImage.jpg"));`

EDIT2: This is obviously now an IDE configuration issue, probably stemming from the fact that I converted an old project into one using Maven. I don't really understand how it is misconfigured though. My folder structure is:

> src/main/java
>   src/main/resources

My classpath has one entry for "src" `<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>`

If I right click on the `/main/resources/images/` folder and Use as Source Folder it turns the classpathentry into this `<classpathentry excluding="main/resources/images/" kind="src" path="src"/>` and creates a new one like this `<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources/images"/>`. It also doesn't work.

EDIT3: Okay this is really dumb but I just realized what the issue is. I'm not actually using Maven for local development builds. It's using Eclipse's built in Ant configuration or whatever. Maven is used for the automated deployment builds, hence the issue. Sorry to waste everyone's time.

Comment: In JAR there is only `\images\blah`, `\main\resources\images\blah` is wrong way to access resources from JAR. What do you mean by 'I reference the resource files', showe code.

Comment: Yes, but then I have to deal with two separate paths - one for development and one for deployment. I understand this may be a common scenario but I'm asking if there's an easy, elegant way to avoid this.

Answer (score 3):

This should work from IDE and from JAR.

```
getClass().getResource("images/lightboardImage.jpg");
```

Files from `src/main/resources` are copied to `target/classes`.

During runtime, all resources should be visible from classpath as `images/lightboardImage.jpg`. This works from IDE for me. If not, check your IDE configuration as said @juanluisrp.

Java executed from my IDE looks like this:

```
java  -classpath (...) /home/.../target/classes (...)
```

So, the runtime classpath is configured to `target/classes` directory.

Comment: The problem isn't how to address paths once they are loaded in the JAR, the problem is the fact that they are in two different locations within the devlopment environment and deployment environment. I can use `getClass().getResource("images\lightboardImage")` in the JAR file and it works fine. The problem is now I have to deal with two different paths, `"/main/resources/images/lightboardImage"` and `"images/lightboardImage"`.

Comment: No, when you execute program, there is one runtime path accessible like this: `images/lightboardImage`

Answer (score 3):

During the lifecycle of Maven, resources are copied to `target/classes`. When the JAR is assembled `target/classes` content goes to the JAR root. So, if you want to load a resource that is in the JAR you can use

```
getClass().getResource("/images/lightboardImage.jpg"));
```

From the IDE it should work with the same path unless you don't have classpath properly configured. If you are using Eclipse check that `src/main/resources` is marked as source folder.

Comment: I have a feeling this is the issue. I just have one src classpathentry... `<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>`. Should I explicitly include main\resources?

Comment: Which IDE are you using? If it is Eclipse, has it the maven plugin installed?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you need to set your IDE to point to `src/main/resources` as part of the classpath. Then you can use `getClass().getResource("images\lightboardImage")` for both running under maven and from your IDE.

For example, in Eclipse you would do this by right-clicking on `src/main/resources` in the Project Explorer and clicking `"Build Path" -> "Use as Source Folder"`

Comment: Yes I realized that as the issue after juanluis' comment. This seems conceptually odd... are resource folders always supposed to be configured this way?

Comment: It's relative to the compiled classes in the classpath, not the original source folders. Maven copies the resource and java folder into the target.  Eclipse just copies everything not java in it's source folders into the target folder. If you have java files in folder and other stuff in another, eclipse doen't care. When using ant (or javac) you need to do the copying yourself as a separate task. I suppose that the Maven crowd thinks it's a bit unclean to mix java with other files, personally I think it's an inconvenience that requires a lot of directory traversing when looking for things...